# querying multipe documents of acollection

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

[image of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSuZw.png)I have a collection in the firebase `firestore` inside which I have multiple documents. I want to retrieve a document based on the data field which is present in the document how can I do this in android.
I have done this

```
firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference collectionReference = firebaseFirestore.collection("Planes");
Query query = collectionReference.whereEqualTo("starting",startAirport).whereEqualTo("destination",destinationAirport);
 FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Planes> response = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Planes>()
                .setQuery(query, Planes.class)
                .build();
        firestoreRecyclerAdapter= new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Planes,PlaneViewHolder>(response) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public PlaneViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
              View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.planes_item,parent,false);
                return new PlaneViewHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PlaneViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Planes model) {
                     holder.book.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(View v) {
                             DocumentSnapshot snapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                             final String DocId= snapshot.getId();
                             Intent intent=new Intent(PlaneRequestActivity.this,UserDetails.class);
                             intent.putExtra("Document",DocId);
                             intent.putExtra("tripId",tripId);
                             startActivity(intent);
                         }
                     });
                             holder.setPlanes(model);


            }
            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                super.onError(e);
                Toast.makeText(PlaneRequestActivity.this,"Error:"+e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };
        plane.setAdapter(firestoreRecyclerAdapter);
    }
```

it works for only the first document. It didn't find the second Document of the Collection

Comment: Please post full code

Comment: this is the main code after this i have used the recyclerAdapter to show them inside the activity.

Comment: post database structure

Comment: posted the structure

Comment: so both of them have same desination and starting point ?

Comment: no each document have different destination and starting point

Comment: There are only 2 documents

Comment: Please also add a screenshot of the second document. What are the values of `startAirport` and `destinationAirport` used in the query? What is the expected result? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: the startAirport and destinationAirport are the values which come from anotherActivity and has the same value as the value of the fields of the document@AlexMamo

Comment: Please also add a screenshot of the second document. What is the expected result? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: i want the whole document which has starting and destination equalsto  startAirport and @AlexMamo

Comment: Please also add a screenshot of the second document.